# how to write api like a vectormagic

Tags: image-processing, vectorization

I want to write api like a  http://vectormagic.com and I want to know what kind of technologies you will advise me(I know php,html,js,..,c++) to use?
Other documentation and advices will be appreciated.
Thank's

Comment: How much experience do you have with image processing?

Answer (score 1):

Oh man, this practically has nothing to do with technologies, rather with processing algorithms. I don't have experience with such tool internals, but my best bet is that there goes A LOT of math. One needs to:

1. Extract bunch of curves from image, which represents edges in picture.
2. Construct arbitrary number of shapes composed of previous extracted curves. Construction of shapes possibly should be done in such a way that minimizes total number of shapes and/or number of different pixels between original and vector form of image and possibly something else...
3. Fill constructed shapes with corresponding color and/or color gradient and/or somehow else...

1 and 2 means that program automatically extracts and merges big number of mathematical formulas representing curves/shapes in image. I can't imagine other way of achieving this than using some form of [genetic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming). But this can be limitation of my knowledge and/or imagination also :-)

good luck !